# Using QPainter in non-GUI environment

Tags: linux, qt, server, qpainter

Using QPainter in a non-GUI environment may be useful f.e. to generate PDF's on (web)servers.

However `QPainter` depends on `QGuiApplication`, which results in a runtime error:

> qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display
>   Could not connect to any X display.

How could I use `QPainter` in a non-GUI environment (no output screen is available)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should start your application with the following command line argument: [`-platform minimal`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#platformName-prop):

> *minimal* is provided as an examples for developers who want to write their own platform plugins. However, you can use the plugin to **run GUI applications in environments without a GUI, such as servers**.

Note that `-platform offscreen` seems to be required to support fonts, i.e. painting text, otherwise black squares are shown instead of the actual text.

**Further reading & references**

- [Getting font metrics without GUI (console mode)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31732698/getting-font-metrics-without-gui-console-mode)
- https://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/interest/2016-June/022942.html
- [QPainter.drawText() SIGSEGV Segmentation fault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26205461/qpainter-drawtext-sigsegv-segmentation-fault)
- [What is the use of various Qt platform plugins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21488072/what-is-the-use-of-various-qt-platform-plugins)